# Cloudant attachment Authorization

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

Node JS + Cloudant - I am trying to link a video stored in cloudant via Node.js app using HTML5 video tag. I get challenged for cloudant credentials on page load. How do I access the attachment without being challenged for credentials? Video URL format: http://apikey:pwd@username.cloudant.com/docid/video.mpg4

(I pass the API key in the URL)

2.) Is there a way to proxy attachment URL in cloudant without exposing the API key and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you make sure the URL is over SSL, Cloudant will only accept a connection over https.

Also, the URL structure for connecting to an image should be:

`https://$USERNAME.cloudant.com/$DATABASE/$DOCUMENT_ID/$ATTACHMENT`

So I created the example:

`https://elsmore.cloudant.com/attachmenttest/testpng/pouchdb.png`

And with an API key setup with just `Reader` permissions you can access it via without being challenged:

`https://medstiessitypichaverecti:cb2a6e5ef5af62c3e6fdad312d48fe005a8aa698@elsmore.cloudant.com/attachmenttest/testpng/pouchdb.png`

I'd suggest having a read only API key if you wish to expose it directly to the browser/end user or to put these in a separate database with `Reader` permissions for Everybody (*highly* recommend against this last option)

Comment: Update: This solution does not work. Just want to update in case if this helps other, I ended up using a middleware. One other advantages using this approach is to use Node streaming capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it shouldn't be possible to link with a token.

Anyway you could create a workaround directly in your node.js code: you could add an URL referring to your application which could be proxied through node engine to the cloudant service instance adding any additional parameters.

For example:
http://[YOURAPPNAME].mybluemix.net/forcloudant/video.mpg4

will be make node engine (so without exposing any parameter to the client through an HTTP request from the client's browser) to send a get request to

http://apikey:pwd@username.cloudant.com/docid/video.mpg4

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot. I am kind of confused isn't the whole point of CouchDB or for that case cloudant built on top of CouchDB is to let stream your content to browser vs going through a middleware?